# Фантомный клик в datagridview при использовании Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz

Есть `datagridview`. В последних колонках `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. При нажатии запускаю таску. Всё работает. Каждые 60 сек запускается задача. Однако, каждую минуту также система кликает на datagridview. Как будто вместе с задачей запускается клик. Не пойму где собака зарыта

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     scheduler = factory.GetScheduler().Result;
     scheduler.Start().Wait();
}

 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == this.btncolumn.Index)
        {
            var data = db.Table<DB>().Where(x => x.Id == id).First();
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

            AddJob(id.ToString(), data.Login, data.Password, data.Provider);

        }
        
    }
} 
 public void AddJob(string jobname, string login, string password, string provider)
    {
        HelloJob.CurrentForm = this;
                
    
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
            .WithIdentity(jobname, "group1")
            .UsingJobData("login", login)
            .UsingJobData("password", password)
            .UsingJobData("provider", provider)
            .Build();
    
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(jobname, "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInSeconds(60)
            .RepeatForever())
            .Build();
    
            _ = scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger).Result;
    
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

public class HelloJob : IJob
    {
        public HelloJob()
        {
        }

        public string GetBalance(string login, string password, string provider)
        {   
            return "0";
        }

        public static Form1 CurrentForm = null;
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

            var login = dataMap.GetString("login").ToString();
            var password= dataMap.GetString("password").ToString();
            var provider = dataMap.GetString("provider").ToString();
            var balance = GetBalance(login, password, provider);
            if (CurrentForm.InvokeRequired)
            {

                Form1.ExecuteCallback x = new Form1.ExecuteCallback(CurrentForm.Execute);
                x(balance, login);
                CurrentForm.Invoke(x);
                CurrentForm.Execute(balance, login);

            }
            else
            {
                CurrentForm.Execute(balance, login);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Как вы поняли, что это клик?

Comment: @aepot при отладке каждую минуту попадает в dataGridView1_CellClick

Comment: Можно попробовать [донастроить](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0b53e456-07a6-4cfb-a3e4-5a0e6ee23284/tracking-methodevent-calls?forum=csharpgeneral) студию, чтобы она ловила стек вызовов для события, таким образом определить, откуда было вызвано событие.